# Dependabot отправляет два запроса на слияние для каждого изменения версии

Tags: python, github, зависимости, dependabot

У меня есть репозиторий на GitHub (написан на Python). В нём есть каталог `dev_requirements/` с файлами `mypy_requirements.txt`, `pylint_requirements.txt` и `tests_requirements.txt` - зависимости для запуска MyPy, Pylint и тестов соответственно. Такая структура была выбрана для того, чтобы можно было писать в GitHub Action'ах что-то вроде `python -m pip install -r ./dev_requirements/mypy_requirements.txt`. Также есть файл `requirements.txt` (в корневом каталоге) с зависимостями самого проекта.

Я подключил Dependabot'а, вот содержимое файла `.github/dependabot.yml`:

```yml
version: 2
updates:
- package-ecosystem: pip
  directory: "/"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
    time: "10:00"
```

И теперь при обновлении какой-нибудь зависимости из файла `dev_requirements/*_requirements.txt` Dependabot присылает два запроса на слияния (пулл реквеста), например, с такими заголовками:

- `Bump mypy from 1.7.1 to 1.8.0`
- `Bump mypy from 1.7.1 to 1.8.0 in /dev_requirements`

Как это решить, чтобы он отправлял только один запрос на слияние?

PS: как проходит обновление не в `dev_requirements/*`, а просто в `requirements.txt` - незнаю, такого ещё ни разу не было.

PSS: вот ссылка на репозиторий, если надо - https://github.com/wchistow/pystackapi.

Comment: Это похоже на баг (есть смысл попробовать добавить issue в репозитории депендабота). А так можно попробовать добавить отдельный раздел для `directory: "/dev_requirements"`, и отдельно для корня. Но не факт что это поможет.

Comment: Еще как вариант, вообще избавиться от файлов *requirements.txt, добавить все зависимости в pyproject.toml в раздел `[project.optional-dependencies]`. Либо использовать что-то типа poetry или pdm, там есть возможность группы зависимостей добавлять. Я использую poetry, dependabot корректно с ним работает.

Comment: @insolor, я делал вот так: https://github.com/wchistow/pystackapi/blob/5178597a25a6caec71b72a54a9b0c6fb7a840379/.github/dependabot.yml - было точно так же.

Comment: Можно попробовать: 1 - в обратном порядке, 2 - время для dev_requirements сделать раньше чем для корня

Comment: @insolor, сделал оба варианта: https://github.com/wchistow/pystackapi/blob/5b99e6798280d8fc9a7a4cbfd4b1fb091b8627a2/.github/dependabot.yml. Когда что-нибудь обновится, посмотрим, работает ли.

Comment: Было бы логично в настройках для `/` исключить папку `dev_requirements`, но такая функция до сих пор [не поддерживается](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275433/can-i-exclude-directories-from-github-dependabot)

Comment: @insolor, теперь всё нормально: dependabot создал только один запрос на слияние! Можете написать ответ с вашим решением.